# On Mac OS X, how can I disable journaling on shutdown and reenable it on boot?

Tags: macos, boot, journaling

The why: I want to share a home partition with Ubuntu, but I don't want to give up journaling while booted into Mac OS X (Snow Leopard) if I don't have to.

What I've figured out:

The commands I want are

```
diskutil disableJournal /Users
```

and

```
diskutil enableJournal /Users
```

(The volume is mounted on `/Users`)

`rc.local` and `rc.local.shutdown` looked promising at first, but I think there's a dependency which rules them out.

I tried to make a `StartupItem`, but it wasn't running.

What I'm looking for:

What is an explanation of how to make a `StartupItem` specifically for this? I have the gist of it, but I'm missing some subtleties.

What is an explanation of why a `StartupItem` is the wrong way to go about is and a suggested course of action?

Is there a really obvious easy solution or is this entire endeavor is pointless? What is the explanation?

Comment: I have the same deal on my Macbook Air. I have two partitions—one for the OS and one for all Users, which I mount at /Users. When I run the sudo diskutil disableJournal /Users command I get: "An error occurred journaling the file system: The underlying task reported failure on exit (-69860)". I would love to see this feature, because now I boot to linux from an external drive using rEFIt. For now I am going to login OSX as root and disable journaling permanently until this question is properly answered.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, what version of OS X are you in?

Second, just a clarification: I assume the reason you need to disable journaling is that Ubuntu doesn't support reading and/or writing to HFS+ Journaled volumes?

Or, wait, what in the world....

`diskutil disableJournal` takes a path to a volume, not to an arbitrary folder.

So, if your home folder is located on the root drive, in /Users/, you would do something like

```
diskutil disableJournal /
```

Or do you have a volume named Users? If so, you would use:

```
diskutil disableJournal /Volumes/Users
```

Okay, both `rc` and the `StartupItem` method have been deprecated for some time. Both have basically been replaced by `launchd`, which has taken over the place of `init` (I think, anyway, you'll notice launchd is PID 1).

While I think StartupItems are still supported in 10.6, rc is officially unsupported, as `man rc` states:

> **rc.local** is now unsupported and has been replaced with `launchd(8)`, which
>        bootstraps itself via the `launchctl(1)` bootstrap subcommand to read in
>        `launchd(8)` jobs from the standard locations.

You can check the following for LaunchAgent and LaunchDaemon definition files:

```
 ~/Library/LaunchAgents         Per-user agents provided by the user.
 /Library/LaunchAgents          Per-user agents provided by the adminis-
                                trator.
 /Library/LaunchDaemons         System-wide daemons provided by the admin-
                                istrator.
 /System/Library/LaunchAgents   Per-user agents provided by Mac OS X.
 /System/Library/LaunchDaemons  System-wide daemons provided by Mac OS X.
```

Comment: Actually I have the volume mounted in /Users.  Also, I'm on Snow Leopard.

Comment: From what I've read, `LaunchDaemons` aren't guaranteed to run at boot or shutdown, just before they're needed.

Comment: Ubuntu does support reading a journaled HFS+ volume, but not writing.

Comment: diskutil disableJournal /Volumes/DiscName worked form me on Ventura 13.4.1 Thanks a lot for the answer.